# Proving a norm is a valid norm on a space of functions

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm having trouble proving $\sum_{i=0}^k max_{x\in[0,1]}[|f^i(x)|]$ is a norm on $C^k([0,1],\mathbb{R}$] where $f^i$ is the i-th derivative of f and $f^0$ is the function f its self.

Let $C^k([0,1],\mathbb{R}$] be the space of all functions that have continuous derivatives on [0,1] up to and including order k.

My current thought is to verifying the three principles (positivity, scaling and, triangle inequality)? The derivative in the norm is what is causing me to doubt my original method though.

Comment: There's no other way of doing this, except to verify the properties of the norm you mentioned (and that $\|x\|=0$ iff $x=0$). So why not just list out your attempts at each?